# Android change background color of android.R.drawable.gallery_thumb

Tags: android, user-interface, view, drawable, background-color

I have the following line of code to change the background of my tab in SherlockFragment

```
view.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.gallery_thumb));
```

This android.R.drawable.gallery_thumb is so cool and gives a bordering around my tab but also changes the background color of my tab to black. Is there a way I can have gallery_thumb but keep the background color to gray?!

Comment: try with view.setImageDrawable()

Comment: @Esteam this is inside onCreateView of SherlockFragment.